# Render nested form in bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Working on Rails 5, 
I am trying to render nested form (same model) in each dynamic tab,
but now the same fomr is rendering in the all the tabs,how to render different fieldset in different tabs

**views/material_masters/new.html.erb**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="tabbable-line">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
          <% @part_locations.each.with_index do |l, i| %>
          <li <%= 'class="active"' if i == 0 %>>
            <a href="#<%= l.location_name %>" data-toggle="tab"> <%= l.location_name %> </a>
          </li>
          <% end %>
          <li><button type="button" class="fa fa-plus btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></button> </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <% @part_locations.each.with_index do |l, i| %>
          <div class="tab-pane <%= 'active' if  i == 0 %>" id="<%= l.location_name %>">
            <%= f.fields_for :material_locations do |builder| %>
            <%= render 'material_location_fields', :f => builder  %>
            <% end %>
            <%= link_to_add_association "Add", f, :material_locations, class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs"  %>
          </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**views/material_masters/_material_location_fields.html.erb**

```
<fieldset>
  <div class= "nested-fields">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <%= f.label :material_location, "Material Location" %>
      <%= f.text_field :mat_location,class:"form-control",required: true %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <%= f.label :opening_stock  %>
      <%= f.text_field :opening_stock ,class:"form-control",onKeyPress:"return NumbersOnly(this, event,true)",required: true  %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <%= f.label :reorder_qty %>
      <%= f.text_field :reorder_qty, class:"form-control",onKeyPress:"return NumbersOnly(this, event,true)",required:true  %>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

**model/material_master.rb**

```
class MaterialMaster < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :material_locations
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :material_locations,allow_destroy: true
 end
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6Ssr.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/69h3X.png

Hear i am trying to add location in bangalore tab i am addling mumbai location and in delhi tab i want to add one more material location but the same form is coming in the next tab

Comment: Please format your code, it's hard to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: can you please show us html source?

Comment: I have edited my question and added related images

Comment: I am trying to pass index value to the fields how to pass index value to the each field

Answer (score 0):

What is obviously on your code is that you have space here in a line:

```
<a href="#<%= l  .location_name %>" data-toggle="tab"> <%= l.location_name %> </a>
```

as you can note l .location_name can you remove the space?